# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

As we enter the second week of the public beta, we desperately need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

UPDATE: @KennyTM just got his moderator access. It took us a bit longer to get him online so... welcome!

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: My congratulations to Isaac--he has nicely answered many questions as well as been heavily involved on meta, and he certainly deserves it.

Comment: Congratulations Isaac, and thanks for volunteering!

Comment: Yay Isaac! Now you can tell us all those juicy secrets about mod powers. :D

Comment: @Akhil,Kaestur,BBischof: Thank you all.  ♦mod powers: close/reopen with single vote, edit/delete just about anything, CW whole question and its answers in one move, lock/protect questions, lock answers, merge questions/tags, see even more details of stuff than the 10k-tools, see ♦mod-aimed flagging of stuff, suspend users, set tag synonyms without going through the voting... probably some other stuff I haven't noticed yet.

Comment: A list can be found of [moderator tools](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) and [10k tools](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users). Isaac covered most of the mod-specific ones.

Comment: I think we've got a good thing going here.  Thank you Isaac, Katie, and Kaestur for volunteering your time.

Answer (score 11):

You overlooked Akhil Mathew...